# How do I write a shell script using node to run multiple javascript files one after the other?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shell

I want to write a .sh file to run multiple javascript files.

I know that I need the following lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
chmod u+x ./a/file1.js ./a/file2.js
```

Is it correct to put two .js files one after the other? I need file1.js to execute first and then file2.js because some of the functions from file2.js need information outputted from file1.js.

I'm also a bit confused with the difference between `#!/usr/bin/env node` and `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. Will I still be able to run my .js files with `bash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#!/usr/bin/env node` sets the environment to Node.js which is a JavaScript environment.

For example if you create a simple script `test.js` with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// now we're in JavaScript!
var d = new Date();

console.log('Current Time: ' + d);
```

Afterwards you make it executable:

```
$ chmod u+x test.js
```

Then you can execute it in the shell:

```
$ test.js
Current Time: Sun Nov 13 2016 07:14:15 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

The file extension doesn't matter:

```
$ mv test.js test.sh
$ test.sh
Current Time: Sun Nov 13 2016 07:15:05 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

If you don't want to change your JavaScript files so that they become shell scripts then you can run them from a shell script using Node.

tasks.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
node ./a/file1.js
node ./a/file2.js
```

Afterwards make it executable and run it:

```
$ chmod u+x tasks.sh
$ tasks.sh
```

Comment: I want to run the tasks.sh file with as little work as possible.

Comment: Sorry I submitted my response too early. Can I include chmod u+x  in my tasks.sh file so that I do not include it in the command line? 

Also, can I make this: #!/usr/bin/env bash my first line of the .sh file and still run node?

Comment: The command `chmod u+x` gives the user (owner) executable permissions for the file. You only need to do this once. `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the first line of the script file specifies that the script is to use the bash interpreter, you can still run node within the script.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#!/bin/sh
node ./a/file1.js
node ./a/file2.js
```

Because:

`#!/usr/bin/env node` causes the program node to be run passing this script as its first argument. `#!/usr/bin/env bash` causes bash to be run. Since the script is a bash script, you want the latter.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env node` causes the program `node` to be run passing this script as its first argument. `#!/usr/bin/env bash` causes `bash` to be run. Since the script is a bash script, you want the latter.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think I will write out my script as: 

#!/usr/bin/env bash
node ./a/file1.js
node ./a/file2.js

Do you know if chmod u+x should also be part of my shell script? What is the use of it?

Comment: `chmod` should not be part of the script. It's something you'd typically do just one time after creating the script. You don't need to chmod the *.js files, only the shell script.